# Find Google Drive Files uploaded today

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to know how I could access only files uploaded to a Google Drive folder today using Apps Script.  I have a large folder of CSVs and I'm uploading new data to BigQuery on a daily basis.  I only want to upload new CSVs, hence why I'm looking to filter out just files uploaded today.

Comment: Try DriveActivity API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
function main() {
  var csv_files = get_a_list_of_fresh_csv_files(); // <---- here are your files

  // do stuff
  csv_files.forEach(file => console.log(file.title, file.id));

  // make an array with IDs of the found files
  var ids_array = csv_files.map(file => file.id);

  console.log(ids_array);
}

function get_a_list_of_fresh_csv_files() {
  var date = new Date(); // today
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1); // yesterday
  date = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT', 'yyy-MM-dd'); // date object --> string

  var list = Drive.Files.list({
    q: "title contains '.csv' and trashed = false and modifiedDate > '" + date + "'"
  });

  return list.items;
}
```

Make sure the 'Drive API' is enabled:

[image]

[image]

**Update**

To find today's files I think you can change the function this way:

```
function get_a_list_of_fresh_csv_files() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyy-MM-dd');
  date += 'T00:00:00';

  var list = Drive.Files.list({
    q: "title contains '.csv' and trashed = false and modifiedDate > '"
       + date + "'"
  });

  return list.items;
}
```

I haven't tried it yet. Let me know if it works. Pretty often there is problem with Time Zone. It can wrong recalculate the file's time for your time zone (especially if the files were made in a different time zone). It's need try and see'.

Comment: How would I go about storing the IDs in either a list or array?

Comment: In this snippet you’re getting the array every element of which is an object. Each of the objects has properties. Among the properties is `id`. In the `main()` function  I showed how you can address the array elements to get the IDs. What exactly you trying to do with the files? Do you need an array with IDs? Describe your goal.

Comment: If you need an array of IDs you can all the line `var ids_array = csv_files.map(file => file.id);` in the `main()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much this has been a big help!! I just have one last question.  Is there a way to change the code so that instead of looking at files created in the last 24 hours we are looking at files created since the start of today?

Comment: I've added the update to my answer. Try it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yuri you're a savior it works exactly how I want!!